# Refreshing a counter++ for every new file

Tags: java, counter

If I have four different files that I'm passing through a loop with `count++` how would I get the `count++` to refresh and start at 1 for every new file?

Right now, the output for the files is:

```
20    
37  
57  
76
```

But I want it to refresh and start at 1, so the output would be:

```
20    
17    
20   
16
```

My code in entirety:

```
import java.io.File;
```

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Grader {

```
public static int Score = 0;

public static void getFileInfo(String fileName)
        throws FileNotFoundException {


    Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

    while (in.hasNext()) { 
    String fileContent = in.nextLine();
    String result = removeSpaces(fileContent);

    double first = Double.parseDouble(fileContent.substring(0, fileContent.indexOf(" ")));
    char operator = getOperator(fileContent);
    double second = secondNumber(result, fileContent);
    double last = Double.parseDouble(result.substring(result.indexOf("=") + 1));

    double math = mathChecking(first, second, operator);

    mathGrading(math , last);

    }
    System.out.println(Score);

}

public static String removeSpaces(String content){
    String result = content.replace(" ","");
    return result;
}

public static double mathGrading(double math , double last) {

    if (math == last){
        Score++;
    }
    return Score;   
}

public static double secondNumber(String result, String opContent){

    int checkAdd = opContent.indexOf('+');
    int checkMinus = opContent.indexOf('-');
    int checkMulti = opContent.indexOf('*');
    int checkDivi = opContent.indexOf('/');

    if (checkAdd != -1){
        return Double.parseDouble(result.substring(result.indexOf('+')+1 , result.indexOf('='))); 
    }   
    else if (checkMinus != -1) {
        return Double.parseDouble(result.substring(result.indexOf('-')+1 , result.indexOf('='))); 
    }
    else if (checkMulti != -1) {
        return Double.parseDouble(result.substring(result.indexOf('*')+1 , result.indexOf('='))); 
    }
    else if (checkDivi != -1){
        return Double.parseDouble(result.substring(result.indexOf('/')+1 , result.indexOf('='))); 
    }
    return 0;
}


public static char getOperator(String fileContent){


    int checkAdd = fileContent.indexOf('+');
    int checkMinus = fileContent.indexOf('-');
    int checkMulti = fileContent.indexOf('*');
    int checkDivi = fileContent.indexOf('/');

    if (checkAdd != -1){
        char operator = fileContent.charAt(fileContent.indexOf('+')); 
        return operator;
    }   
    else if (checkMinus != -1) {
       char operator = fileContent.charAt(fileContent.indexOf('-'));
       return operator;
    }
    else if (checkMulti != -1) {
        char operator = fileContent.charAt(fileContent.indexOf('*'));
        return operator;
    }
    else if (checkDivi != -1){
        char operator = fileContent.charAt(fileContent.indexOf('/'));
        return operator;
    }
    return ' ';
}

public static double mathChecking(double first, double second, char operator){

    double math = 0;
    if (operator == '+'){
        return math = (first + second);
    }
    else if (operator == '-'){
        return math = (first - second);
    }
    else if (operator == '*'){
        return math = (first * second);
    }
    else if (operator == '/'){
        return math = (first / second);
    }

    return math;
}
```

Here's the Starter class:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

  public class Starter {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {


    Grader.getFileInfo("data\\studentSubmissionA.txt");
    Grader.getFileInfo("data\\studentSubmissionA2.txt");
    Grader.getFileInfo("data\\studentSubmissionB.txt");
    Grader.getFileInfo("data\\studentSubmissionB2.txt");
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Removed answer because it was no use of trying to guess what you mean. Just reset your counter to 1 when you have a new file, very simple.

Comment: That would be nice if I actually understood what you mean. I don't know how to reset it.

Comment: `count = 0`. That's a reset.

Comment: @CherryBomb95 Just do `variable = 0;`. Beat me to it, Jeroen. :)

Comment: public static int Score = 0;   Thats currently what I have but I still get the output from before.

Comment: I just have an if statement that checks if two things are equal, and if they are, it does the Score++;

Comment: What I mean is are you checking each file individually, or all in one loop?

Comment: If you post the code of the loop, I'm sure someone will correct it for you ;)

Comment: The entirety of my code is pretty long, and roughly 120 lines. :/

Comment: That's fine. Just post it.

Comment: There's another class that sends the files, so let me know if you need that too.

Comment: Sure, that would be great.

Comment: Let me know if you need the files too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the getFileInfo method to the following:

```
public static void getFileInfo(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {

Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
Score = 0;

    while (in.hasNext()) { 
    String fileContent = in.nextLine();
    String result = removeSpaces(fileContent);

    double first = Double.parseDouble(fileContent.substring(0, fileContent.indexOf(" ")));
    char operator = getOperator(fileContent);
    double second = secondNumber(result, fileContent);
    double last = Double.parseDouble(result.substring(result.indexOf("=") + 1));

    double math = mathChecking(first, second, operator);

    mathGrading(math , last);

    }
    System.out.println(Score);

}
```

Comment: It just return 1 repeatedly.

Comment: Do you have the same ammount of operations to grade in each file?

Comment: In those four files, yes.

Comment: There are 20 lines in the first 8 files, 10 lines in the 9th file, and 8 lines in the last two files.

Comment: So I updated it for the first 8 files, for the others I'll keep working.

Comment: It still prints 1, but only once now.

Comment: Is `count` = to 0 or 1? Try the other of the one you have.

Comment: I changed it to 1, since I accidentally set it to 0, but now it just prints 2.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42004/discussion-between-hichris123-and-cherrybomb95)